# python: sth like parametrized inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

I want my classes `X` and `Y` to have a method `f(x)` which calls a function `func(x, y)` so that `X.f(x)` always calls `func(x, 1)` and `Y.f(x)` always calls `func(x, 2)`

```
class X(object):
    def f(self, x):
        func(x, 1)

class Y(object):
    def f(self, x):
        func(x, 2)
```

But I want to place `f` in a common base class `B` for `X` and `Y`. How can I pass that value (1 or 2) when I inherit `X` and `Y` from `B`? Can I have sth like this (C++ like pseudocode):

```
class B(object)<y>:  # y is sth like inheritance parameter
    def f(self, x):
        func(x, y)

class X(B<1>):
    pass

class Y(B<2>):
    pass
```

What techniques are used in Python for such tasks?

Comment: @S. Lott: Maybe this sth...?  http://stackoverflow.com/users/56338/sth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a class decorator (Python 2.6 and up) if you just want to add a common function to several classes (instead of using inheritance).

```
def addF(y):
    def f(self, x):
        return "Hello", x, "and", y

    def decorate(cls):
        cls.f = f
        return cls

    return decorate


@addF(1)
class X(object):
    pass

@addF(2)
class Y(object):
    pass

print X().f("X")
print Y().f("Y")

>>> 
Hello X and 1
Hello Y and 2
```

Comment: Seems to be the solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Python is more flexible than you give it credit.

I think you want something like this:

```
class B(object):
    def f(self,x):
        func(x, self.param)

class X(B):
    param=1

class Y(B):
    param=2
```

**NB**

- note the method f has self as the
  first parameter.
- the param= lines are class variables.